# Refereeing papers on behalf of a professor: should it be listed on a CV?

Tags: cv, peer-review

My professor sometimes asks me to referee papers for him. 
Should I list the corresponding journals in the professionals activity section of my CV?

Comment: Related, but not a dupe http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11382/what-is-the-correct-protocol-for-including-peer-reviews-that-i-have-done-in-a-cv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if your professor explicitly lists you as a reviewer or sub-reviewer with the program committee of the conference/journal; no if your review is then edited by your professor before submission.

Comment: This is a very good point.  If you are an official referee, recognized as such by the journal, then you can certainly list it on your CV.  If you are just helping your advisor out behind the scenes, with no official recognition, then you shouldn't list it.  The reason is that listing it on your CV shows two things: that you are doing your duty and that editorial boards view you as an expert.  If you're not the official referee, then you are still doing your duty, but it's not a sign of expertise (your advisor might have asked you more as a learning experience than to get your expert opinion).

Comment: I disagree with the last point; even if your review is edited by your advisor, you are still a coauthor of the review and you still deserve credit.  **Do not agree to review "on behalf of" someone else without explicit permission from the journal/conference.** The editor _might_ be seriously unhappy with the idea that your professor isn't actually writing the review that they agreed to write.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. It is the very prototype of service to the professional community that you want to show that you are willing to perform.

The question that Scrooge linked to has good advice for how to do so.