# Should I list the journals/conferences that I have reviewed for in my personal website?

Tags: peer-review, cv, website

I have been thinking about this question for a while now. I could see some advice in [a.SE1](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11382/what-is-the-correct-protocol-for-including-peer-reviews-that-i-have-done-in-a-cv) and [a.SE2](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/do-you-list-journals-you-have-reviewed-for-on-your-cv) that answers for the inclusion of such activities in a CV.

However, is it a good idea to list such details on my personal website?

*My present webpage does not contain my CV -- It just lists list of publications, projects, and some stuff like academics backgrounds. And, I don't want to put my CV later either.*

Comment: I don't list them because I'm being bombarded by review requests as it is!

Comment: If you don't have your CV on the homepage, why would you want this list?

Answer (score 5):

In general, People's websites tend to be less formal and more detailed, so I say go for it, especially because it shows some more well-roundedness and "giving back."