# Disclosing peer review results

Tags: publications, research-process, peer-review

My paper was recently published and I submitted a report to my institution for a promotion. However, the research administrator asked me to provide a copy of peer review of my paper, which was reviewed in double-blind. The purpose was for the "validity" of my paper. This is strange and new to me because I never encountered this before. Is it ethical to disclose peer review from a double blind review outside between the author and the editor?

Comment: Is the double-blind part relevant here? I've seen reviews being shared in single-blind.

Comment: This is a peer review of your paper. Yes, I would say you can do with it what you want. What you cannot do is disclose your peer review of someone else's paper.

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11097/ethics-of-publishing-received-peer-reviews (but there is an important difference, I think, between publishing a received review vs privately sharing it)

Answer (score 13):

Additionally to what Buffy wrote, there are many issues arising with predatory journals stating that they are doing peer review when they actually are just pocketing author publishing charges. If you get any peer review from these journals, it is usually just something non-committal ("Nice work!"). So submitting your peer-review will show that actual peer-review took place.

I try to engage with papers I am reviewing, asking lots of questions that pop up. And I correct comma errors, which seem to be so prevalent these days ;)

Comment: "correct comma errors, which seem to be so prevalent these days", guilty, guilty, guilty. :(

Comment: Do you insert comma errors in your own papers, to test whether they are being carefully peer-reviewed as well? :D

Comment: @lucidbrot, that is actually an excellent idea! My last paper was published with, among others, two English professors. We fought over enough prepositions and commata, if I would have left one out or put one in wrong, I would never hear the end of it :)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can reveal them unless you have also signed a non-disclosure agreement, which I doubt happened.

The purpose of double blind review is to assure honesty and accuracy, not long term secrecy per se.